# What chemicals used everyday will cause an explosive reaction if exposed into outer space?

Tags: reactivity, explosives, atmospheric-chemistry

What chemicals used everyday will cause an explosive reaction if exposed into outer space?

Comment: Well, you're asking for a list, and we don't do lists here. And that whether demanding an answer is acceptable is debatable.

Comment: I figure that if something is going to explode, it's much more likely to do so under our oxygenated atmosphere than in vacuum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example for an everyday chemical that most probably will cause an explosion if exposed into outer space is liquid water at temperatures significantly above 300 K when hold in an inappropriate container.  This phenomenon is called a BLEVE.  But be aware that this is not an chemical reaction.